# Script returning no results for data collection in an API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When trying to copy the API data to the spreadsheet returns blank, I would like to know where I am failing in the script (I believe it is something simple but I am letting go without seeing it)

```
function CartolaMarket() {
  var url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  var table = [['apelido','clube_id','posicao_id','status_id','media_num']];
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var r = results[i];
    var apelido = r.atletas.apelido;
    var clube_id = r.atletas.clube_id;
    var posicao_id = r.atletas.posicao_id;
    var status_id = r.atletas.status_id;
    var media_num = r.atletas.media_num;
    table.push([apelido,clube_id,posicao_id,status_id,media_num]);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);

}
```

Return Data API:

[image]

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R9Naeuvl7ZequmyNwMOR7z_qKWfynxFa7vb6dq9RysU/edit?usp=sharing

Data I intend to collect:

```
apelido
clube_id
posicao_id
status_id
media_num
```

API Link:
https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado

Comment: If you provide the data I'll test the script but I won't run the urlFetchApp on that url

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the reply, I added an image of the API response, it is public from one of the biggest news sites in Brazil. It is reliable, but I understand your precaution.

Comment: I don't want an image.  I want to be able to use the data in testing the rest of the script and I'm definitely not going to type it in myself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I couldn't understand what you need. Because the API is open, everyone can access the data. And the script is written in text format if there is a need to copy. Anyway, I added the spreadsheet link with access to the script and also added what data I want to collect from ```"atletas"``` (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Just provide the text in code format

Comment: In other words provide the JSON.

Comment: Sigh. When people will start paying attention to data structures... Hint: if `atletas` is an array and a top-level property, how come you access skip the indices and try to access item properties directly?

Comment: As said for others please post the whole response from the API. The JSON file. And as pointed by @OlegValter you need to iterate through `atletas` not `results`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to understand the request, the link that I published from the API already shows all the return that it gives in data, there is nothing else that it delivers other than what is listed in "API link". Anyway, in 25 minutes I can already offer bounty for the answers, maybe someone can adjust the script with the details I published in the question. Anyway, thanks to everyone for trying to help! (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @BrondbyIF - please, take a look at what is the type of `atletas` property value and consider what is wrong with accessing the subproperties of it like that: `r.atletas.apelido`. Don't waste rep on that - the question is about a typo.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I really needed to activate the bounty. I am Brazilian and I end up having difficulty understanding English at times, the Portuguese website of StackOverflow is very weak and I end up not getting help there, I need to use it in English but sometimes I have an understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite an answer, just a hint how you could fix it (I hope).

Try this:

```
var r = results[i].atletas[0];
var apelido    = r.apelido;
var clube_id   = r.clube_id;
var posicao_id = r.posicao_id;
var status_id  = r.status_id;
var media_num  = r.media_num;
```

or this:

```
var r = results[i];
var apelido    = r.atletas[0].apelido;
var clube_id   = r.atletas[0].clube_id;
var posicao_id = r.atletas[0].posicao_id;
var status_id  = r.atletas[0].status_id;
var media_num  = r.atletas[0].media_num;
```

Instead of this:

```
var r = results[i];
var apelido = r.atletas.apelido;
var clube_id = r.atletas.clube_id;
var posicao_id = r.atletas.posicao_id;
var status_id = r.atletas.status_id;
var media_num = r.atletas.media_num;
```

Since, as you were told, the `atletas` is an array. You must iterate though it, or take its first element `atletas[0]`, if it's enough.

---

Try this:

```
function CartolaMarket() {

  var url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // loop trough 'atletas', not through 'results'
  var atletas = results.atletas; 

  var table = [['apelido','clube_id','posicao_id','status_id','media_num']];
  for (var i = 0; i < atletas.length; i++) {
    var a = atletas[i];
    var apelido    = a.apelido;
    var clube_id   = a.clube_id;
    var posicao_id = a.posicao_id;
    var status_id  = a.status_id;
    var media_num  = a.media_num;
    table.push([apelido,clube_id,posicao_id,status_id,media_num]);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);

}
```

<s>But I haven't tested this.</s> Looks like it works.